# Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro generalization to $U(n) \to ({Spin(2n) \times U(1)})/{\mathbf{Z}/4}$ for $n=2k+1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, spin-geometry

Atiyah, Bott, and Shapiro paper on [Clifford Modules](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/abs.pdf) around page 10 shows two facts.

### 1 - There is a lift $U(n) \to Spin^c(2n)$ from $U(n) \to SO(2n)\times U(1)$. Also an embedding (injective group homomorphism) $  U(n) \subset Spin^c(2n)$:

ABS show that a homomorphism $U(n) \to SO(2n)\times U(1)$ lifts to $Spin^c(2n)$ and give an explicit description of the lifting in terms of matrices.

Here is the homomorphism they wish to lift:

$l: U(n) \to SO(2n)\times U(1)$ given by $ T \mapsto j(T) \times \det(T)$. (Here $j: U(n) \to SO(2n)$).

Here is their lift $\tilde{l}: U(n) \to Spin^c(2n)$ :

Let $T \in U(n)$ be expressed relative to an orthonormal basis $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $e^{it_1}, e^{it_2} , \ldots e^{it_n}$.  Let $e_1,\ldots,e_{2n}$ be the corresponding basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, so that $e_{2j-1} = f_j$ and $e_{2j} = i f_j$.  Then the corresponding element of $Spin^c(2n)$ is
$$ \tilde{l}(T) = \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \cos (t_j/2) + \sin (t_j/2) e_{2j-1}e_{2j} \right) \times \exp( i \sum t_j /2).$$

### 2 - There is a lift $SU(n) \to Spin(2n)$ from $SU(n) \to SO(2n)$. Also an embedding (injective group homomorphism)  $ SU(n) \subset Spin(2n) $:

Another way to say is this valid fact:
"Does the homomorphism $SU(n) \to SO(2n)$ lift to $SU(n) \to Spin(2n)$?"

We can take $T$ to be in $SU(n)$, *i.e.* take $\prod e^{it_j} =1$.  Then $\exp( i \sum t_j /2) = \pm 1$, so $\tilde l (T)$ is actually in $Spin(2n)$.

### My questions

The above we had shown $ U(n) \subset Spin^c(2n) = \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2}$. However, when $n=2k+1$, the $Spin^c(2n)$ has a ${\mathbf{Z}/4}$ center. So the $Spin(2n)$ and $U(1)$ can share a common normal subgroup $\mathbf{Z}/4$, more than just a $\mathbf{Z}/2$. I want to prove or disprove the following fact

> When $n=2k+1$, is there any valid group homomorphism $$U(n) \to \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}:=\frac{Spin(4k+2) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4} \tag{1}$$ that is also the embedding $  U(n) \subset \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}?$ Namely,
> $$  U(2k+1)=\frac{SU(2k+1) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/(2k+1)} \subset \frac{Spin(4k+2) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}? \tag{2}$$

p.s. If this relation does not hold for general $n=2k+1$, it will be great to know whether certain $n=3,5,7,\dots$, my relations eq.(1) and eq.(2) still hold.

Ref: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abs.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/abs.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by "and the lift"?

Comment: Also, what is $e_{2j-1}e_{2j}$?

Comment: thanks, see ABS paper and also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3318221/955245

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the lift I mean $$U(n) \to \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}$$ via $$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  &Spin^c(2n)= \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2}\\
          &\nearrow &           \downarrow\\
 U(n) & \longrightarrow & \frac{Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}
\end{array}.
$$

Comment: Is this clarification clear?

Comment: Not really. You already have the diagonal and the vertical maps. If you want the triangle to commute, your only option is to take the horizontal map to be their composite.

Comment: Also I think there is a misprint in ABS, it should be $\cos(t_j/2)e_{2j-1}+\sin(t_j/2)e_{2j}$. In any case I have no idea what $e_{2j-1}e_{2j}$ might mean.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე "take the horizontal map to be their composite." – yes, so is that true?

Comment: You mean is this composite embedding?

Comment: I mean, this is a composite embedding/ But whether what I asked in my question - whether embedding is true.

Comment: Sorry, could you please formulate a self-contained question? Embedding cannot be true or false, it is not a statement, it is a map. The combination of words "is there a valid group homomorphism (...) also the embedding (...)" does not parse, neither grammatically nor mathematically. You already have a homomorphism and you want to know whether this homomorphism is an embedding? Or you want to find any embedding?

Comment: Yes, we want to know whether this homomorphism is an embedding! thanks! Also, is there ANY valid group homomorphism eq(1), that is also an embedding eq(2)?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 4):

Let $\omega = e_1e_2\dots e_{2n-1}e_{2n}$.

For $n > 1$, the center of $Spin(2n)$ is $Z(Spin(2n)) = \{\pm 1, \pm\omega\}$. Note that $\omega^2 = (-1)^n$, so

$$Z(Spin(2n)) = \begin{cases} 
\langle -1, \omega\rangle & n\ \text{is even}\\
\langle\omega\rangle & n\ \text{is odd}
\end{cases} \cong \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2 & n\ \text{is even}\\
\mathbb{Z}/4 & n\ \text{is odd.}\end{cases}$$

We also have the central subgroup $\langle i\rangle < U(1)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$, so we can form the quotient of $Spin(2n)\times U(1)$ by the central subgroup $\langle(\omega, i)\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/4$. Denote the quotient by $G$.

As $(\omega, i)^2 = (-1, -1)$, there is a natural map $\varphi : Spin^c(2n) \to G$ which has kernel $\langle[(\omega, i)]\rangle$, so the composite map $\varphi\circ\tilde{l} : U(n) \to G$ has kernel $\ker(\varphi\circ\tilde{l}) = \tilde{l}^{-1}(\langle[(\omega, i)]\rangle)$. Since $\tilde{l}$ is an embedding,  $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$ is injective if and only if $[(\omega, i)] \not\in \tilde{l}(U(n))$.

Suppose $\tilde{l}(T) = [(\omega, i)]$. Note that the coefficient of $\omega$ in $\prod_{j=1}^n \left( \cos (t_j/2) + \sin (t_j/2) e_{2j-1}e_{2j} \right)$ is $\prod_{j=1}^n\sin(t_j/2)$ which is $\pm 1$ if and only if $\sin(t_j/2) = \pm 1$ (and hence $\cos(t_j/2) = 0$) for every $j$. It follows that $e^{it_j} = -1$ for all $j$ so $T = -I$. As $\tilde{l}(-I) = [(\omega, i^n)] = [(\omega, (-1)^ki)]$, we see that $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$ is injective if and only if $k$ is odd.

**Example:** When $k = 0$, the group $G$ is the quotient of $U(1)\times U(1)$ by $\langle(i, i)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$, and the map $U(1) \to G$ is given by $e^{i\theta} \mapsto [(e^{i\theta/2}, e^{i\theta/2})]$  which is not injective because $-1 \mapsto [(i, i)] = [(1, 1)]$.

We also could have taken the quotient of $Spin(2n)\times U(1)$ by the central subgroup $\langle(\omega, -i)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$.  Arguing as above, the induced map on $U(n)$ is injective if and only if $k$ is odd, as before. Note that the quotients are isomorphic as the map $Spin(2n)\times U(1) \to Spin(2n)\times U(1)$, $(g, z) \mapsto (g, z^{-1})$ descends to an isomorphism.

I don't know if there is an embedding $U(n) \to G$ for $k$ even, but if there is, the diagram

\begin{array}{ccc}
 & & Spin^c(2n)\\
 & \nearrow & \downarrow\\
U(n) & \longrightarrow & G 
\end{array}

doesn't commute. For $k = 0$, we have $G \cong U(1)\times U(1)$, so there is an embedding $U(1) \to G$.

Comment: May I confirm your notation, is this ⟨(,)⟩≅ℤ/4? and the ⟨[(,)]⟩ is the kernel of the map :(2)→ ? Are these notations ⟨(,)⟩ and ⟨[(,)]⟩ standard?

Comment: Yes, $(\omega, i) \in Spin(2n)\times U(1)$, and $\langle(\omega, i)\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $(\omega, i)$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$. The image of $(\omega, i)$ under the map $Spin(2n)\times U(1) \to Spin^c(2n)$ is denoted $[(\omega, i)]$. The kernel of the map $\varphi : Spin^c(2n) \to G$ is $\langle[(\omega, i)]\rangle$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$. I'd say this notation is pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks!  I think we have: $$∘̃ :()→$$ $$:(2)→$$ $$̃ :()→(2)$$ to begin with. Could you then clarify this sentence: "Since ̃  is an embedding (based on the ABS paper), ∘̃  is injective if and only if [(,)]∉̃ (())." ? Thanks!

Comment: Why not the other way around? "if and only if [(,)] $\in$ ̃ (()) " ?

Comment: If $[(\omega, i)] = \tilde{l}(A)$, then $(\varphi\circ\tilde{l})(A) = \varphi(\tilde{l}(A)) = \varphi([(\omega, i)]) = [(1, 1)]$ which is the identity of $G$, so $A \in \ker(\varphi\circ\tilde{l})$, so $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$ is not injective.

Comment: thanks, (1) what is your $A$?

Comment: (2)  $A \subset U(n)$?

Comment: (3) In my above, I wrote $T=SU(n)$. Is your notation  $̃ ()=[(,)]$ the same notation of $T$ as mine $T=SU(n)$? thanks! or is that your just some $T \in U(n)$?

Comment: (4) can you illuminate more on the final diagram, is it possible to have an embedding for ()→  for  even and $n=2k+1$, while the diagram doesn't commute? Conversely, if the the diagram commutes, do we have the embedding? In short, are there **necessary or sufficient conditions between the "diagram commute or not" or "embedding"?**

Comment: If $[(\omega, i)] \in \tilde{l}(U(n))$, then there is $A \in U(n)$ such that $\tilde{l}(A) = [(\omega, i)]$. As my previous comment shows, if such an $A$ were to exist, the map $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$ would not be injective. It is possible to have an embedding $U(n) \to G$ for $k$ even while the diagram doesn't commute. This is exactly the point I was trying to make by discussing the $k = 0$ case in my answer.

Comment: In this situation, if you want the diagram to commute, the map $U(n) \to G$ is fixed, it has to be $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$. So there is an embedding $U(n) \to G$ which makes the diagram commute if and only $\varphi\circ\tilde{l}$ is an embedding. If you don't care about the diagram commuting, then you are just asking if there is an embedding $U(n) \to G$ which is a more general question.

Comment: Dear all, Michael and Марина, do any of you know whether $(5)\subset ((10)×(1))//4$ is true or false? This is the same $/4$ as the center of both (10) and (1). This is your $n=5$ and $k=2$ case. Thanks!

Comment: @wonderich: I do not. That's the first case which isn't covered by my answer.